# Oracle group by and pivot

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table in an Oracle 11g database that looks like this:

```
ownerid | propertyid | name
--------------------------------------
1       | 1000001    | SMITH MARY
2       | 1000001    | SMITH JOHN
3       | 1000002    | HUGHES JANE
4       | 1000003    | CHEN ALICE
5       | 1000003    | MCCOY ELLIS
```

I'm trying to group the table on `propertyid` and pivot the rows to columns so that it looks like this:

```
propertyid | owner1         | owner2
---------------------------------------------
10001      | SMITH MARY     | SMITH JOHN
10002      | HUGHES JANE    | <null>
10003      | CHEN ALICE     | MCCOY ELLIS
```

Each property can have between 1 and 3 owners, but I'm only interested in the first two as they appear when ordered on `ownerid`.

My best solution was to create two subqueries: one of "first" owners and another  "second" owners. I used the `nth_value` function as follows:

```
-- first owners
select 
  propertyid,
  nth_value(name, 1) over (partition by propertyid order by ownerid) as owner_1
from owners
```

But this gives me duplicate (although correct) pairs of properties and owners if the total number of owners is greater than 1. In general I feel like there must be a better way of doing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with
     inputs ( ownerid, propertyid, name ) as (
       select 1, 1000001, 'SMITH MARY'  from dual union all
       select 2, 1000001, 'SMITH JOHN'  from dual union all
       select 3, 1000002, 'HUGHES JANE' from dual union all
       select 4, 1000003, 'CHEN ALICE'  from dual union all
       select 5, 1000003, 'MCCOY ELLIS' from dual
     ),
     prep ( propertyid, name, rn ) as (
       select propertyid, name,
              row_number() over (partition by propertyid order by ownerid)
       from   inputs
     )
select * 
from prep
pivot (max(name) for rn in (1 as owner1, 2 as owner2))
order by propertyid
;


PROPERTYID OWNER1      OWNER2
---------- ----------- -----------
   1000001 SMITH MARY  SMITH JOHN
   1000002 HUGHES JANE
   1000003 CHEN ALICE  MCCOY ELLIS

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: This worked great, and I like the `inputs` => `prep` => work pattern. Although I have to admit I was Googling those for a while thinking they were actual Oracle functions :) Thanks!

Comment: lol I hope you found the right answer (WITH clause, CTE, subquery factoring...) I learned it early on and now use it all the time, it makes queries easier to read/follow. Glad it helped. Cheers!